# Blender keep rendering multiple png´s even though I only want to render a single frame

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am relatively new to blender.
Even though I have selected the Output Image to PNG (not movie) and pressed the ordinary rendering button (not animation), Blender keeps rendering the whole scene from frame 1 to 150. I am rendering in Blender Render mode.
The scene is a part of a Smoke physics simulation.
Until recently it was working fine. 
Suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: You probably pressed the animation button (the one that looks like a slate)  or Ctrl+F12, instead of the render (camera icon) button (or F12). Note that when you render a single image it doesn't get saved automatically but you need to save it manually by pressing F3 in the uv/image editor window

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that's not it.
I am in fact pressing the Camera Icon rendering button and not the animation button. Still blender starts rendering multiple frames, just as if it´s creating a movie. It´s odd. Thanks for the tip regarding F3.

Comment: Posting the .blend would be helpful.http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/